# Accessing audio and video songs data that played using blackberry phones

Tags: blackberry, video, audio

I want to make a blackberry app. which will store audio and video files,those are played by BB device (play list) and other information related to those songs (as artist name, album name) on the server.

i succeed to access all audio and video songs that are on BB device, but dont know how to access only those songs ,which are played. And i got those songs only as byte array, how could i get information about those songs?

Does blackberry have any special api for this?

Answer (score 0):

This page in a guide about working with multimedia on the BB may help you. If not, surely something in the guide will answer your question.